# How to Secure Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This image shows the Authentication for my Firebase Database Security: [Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8YMW.png)

1. I only allow Email/Password Sign-in method, everything else is disabled.
2. I don't allow my users to sign in manually.
3. My Android app logs in via code and it uses just one set of Email/Password:

My question is how come I am still getting this warning: [Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTx3M.png)

I've followed thru the [enter link description here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android#7) but this sample uses Google sign-in method. And all the other samples or discussion I've read use the same method. Has anyone here tried Email/Password Sign-in Method? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That authentication and the firebase realtime database are different things. Your authentication method doesn't control who has access to that database.

This means that anyone who has access to the keys, will be able to access your db. So if your client app (Android / ios / web app) access the database directly, your users will be able to do that too.

To secure it you need to use specific read/write rules. Your best explanation will be from their documentation which can be found here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Comment: I modified my rules to this and it got rid of the warning: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null && newData.exists()"
  }
}